# Go Lang How to Mock Package Method?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a method that uses an package method dao.ToVendorId, how can i mock it??

```
func group(context context.Execution, dataStore dataStore) (map[string][]VendorItem, map[string]string, error) {

    for _,info := range dataStore.Items {
        if itemId, err := dao.ToVendorId(context, info.Seller, info.Id); err != nil {
            return vendorItems, vendorDataTranslated, err
        } else {
      //More Code
        }
    }
    return vendorItems, vendorDataTranslated, nil;
}
```

Comment: Replace it with an interface and compose as needed With an appropriate mock.

Comment: Are you trying to mock `dao.ToVendorId` or your `group` function? Need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: i want to  mock dao.ToVendorId to test group function.

Comment: @Sly How can i pass the dao to group function? i'ts not clear to me. Thanks !!